# Retrieve the content of a specific column from a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I want to retrieve the content of a specific column from a `qTableView` which contains 2 columns; the problem is that i can't find a way to access it; i also tried to writing the following code(inspired by another question) but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ui->table->model->rowCount(); i++) {
       QAbstractItemModel index = ui->table->model()->data(ui->table->model()->index(0,i));
       qDebug() << index;
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of [`QAbstractItemModel::data()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) is of type `QVariant`.

The data in the returned `QVariant` depends on the `role` (the second parameter of `data()` which is per default `Qt::DisplayRole`), i.e. in this case `QString` (according to [`Qt::ItemDataRole`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)).

Furthermore, the usage of [`QAbstractItemModel::index()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) looks wrong as well:
First parameter is row index, second parameter is column index.

Putting this alltogether, I recommend the following fix (without having tested):

```
for (int i = 0; i < ui->table->model->rowCount(); ++i) {
  QString value = ui->table->model()->data(ui->table->model()->index(i, 0));
  qDebug() << value;
}
```

to access data of the 1<sup>st</sup> column or

```
for (int i = 0; i < ui->table->model->rowCount(); ++i) {
  QString value = ui->table->model()->data(ui->table->model()->index(i, 1));
  qDebug() << value;
}
```

to access data of the 2<sup>nd</sup> column.